# Getting a great prophet crashes CivV (with mods)?

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-5, mods, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Some friends and I have been playing multiplayer hot-seat games for several months now.  Over several different games, with several different **sets of mods**(the culprit), we have had the same reoccurring issue:

**Building a great prophet crashes the game.**

The only solution we have found so far is to sell our shrines and stop earning faith. I know there are many potential issues here, especially with unofficial mods involved, but I'm wondering if **anyone has come across this before**?

I will provide a list of mods asap.

Comment: Does it do this in vanilla?  If not, chances are pretty good it's your third party mods doing it.

Comment: @Frank I'm pretty sure that its my 3rd party mods. We are investigating further, just wondering if anyone else has seen this.

Comment: hey, why the downvote?

Comment: Downvotes are given if a question *"does not show research effort, is unclear, or not useful"*, as you are probably well aware. As you have clarified in the comments, the cause of the issue is that it is due to third party mods, which unless we get a specific list of all the mods loaded into the game at the time of the occurrence, would probably classify as "unclear" at the very most. And then depending on which mods/how many there are, you are unfortunately not going to get much help clarifying which one it is.

Comment: My suggestion would be that you figure this out for yourself, but unloading all your mods, then loading them back in one at a time, to see which one causes the issue, then add that as an answer.

Comment: There's a good chance that it's two incompatible mods being loaded at the same time, rather than a single problem mod.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing?

Comment: @Ben Thanks, for now my question is "has anyone seen this", and I suppose the answer for now is "no".   I'll update with more details as I investigate.

Comment: I agree @MikeKellogg, as I said it's occurred with various sets of mods for us, so we've eliminated some of the possibilities.

Comment: @Charkz, yes, tried re-installing (and reloading our set of mods) and the issue still occurs. it has also occurred on several different people's PC's with what we believe to be identical setups. It's almost certainly the mods, as Ben suggested, I'll get a list of the mods when home.

Comment: Does everybody playing have the mods and the mods are enabled?